# Why is the assignment method needed when you could just use "=" (from Hartl's Tutorial)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am having a terrible time understanding the assignment function that is needed, as explained in [chapter 8.2.3](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-current_user). of the Hartl's tutorial.

As context, he is focused on the second line of the following `sign_in` function:

```
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user #<-- this line
  end
```

Where he mentions because its an *assignment*, it must be then separately defined as

```
def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end
```

Where the method `current_user=` expressly designed to handle **assignment** to `current_user`.  My confusions is:

1. Why is this even necessary?  I thought that a simple `=` would allow you to assign things.  For example `user.email = hello@kitty.com`
2. Also, when eventually he will code `redirect_to current_user`, how does something that belongs to the `SessionsController` get translated to a view controlled by `UsersController`?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason being it is needed as to avoid confusion (for the interpreter/VM) between method invocation and variable assignment

```
def foo
  # Two completely different things!
  bar = "baz" # assigns baz to local variable bar
  self.bar = "baz" # invokes the bar= method with parameter of baz
end
```

What's happening there is that he is doing two things, firstly invoking the `current_user=` method with the user object and secondly, setting that to `@current_user` (it's not a great example - you'd probably end up doing a lot more in real life if you were to make a `current_user=` method such as setting up session variables).

secondly `redirect_to current_user` is equivalent to `redirect_to user_path(current_user)` - check out http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html for more details which explains the different parameter kinds that redirect_to can take. Note this is a redirect, not a render - so a second HTTP request happens here.